# Urigo: Angular-Meteor: what sort of array is returned when subscribing Mongo Collection through $meteor.collection service

Tags: meteor, angular-meteor

I have subscribed to a MongoDB collection through $meteor service, What I get is an array of docs `plus` some methods embeded on the array.

But whenever I do `JSON.stringify(subscribed_collection)` only json docs are displayed?

Answer (score 0):

The returned object of `$meteor.collection` is [AngularMeteorCollection](http://angular-meteor.com/api/AngularMeteorCollection). here is a usage example from there:
`$scope.notAutoTodos = $scope.$meteorCollection(Todos, false).subscribe("publicTodos");`